# How change layout on ios custom keyboard?

Tags: ios, objective-c, custom-keyboard, ios-extensions

I implementing custom keyboard for ios devices.
i build a layout for english qwerty and load it  when the view is loaded

```
self.keyboard = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"Keyboard" owner:nil options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
self.inputView = (UIInputView*)self.keyboard;
```

i need to add a option to change the layout for 3x4 Keyboard with different layout and size of height.

How can i change the layout after for example button click?

Thanks

This is what i try:

```
self.keyboardSmall = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"KeyboardSmall" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
    self.inputView = (UIInputView*)self.keyboardSmall;

    _heightConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem: self.view
                                                     attribute: NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                                                     relatedBy: NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                        toItem: nil
                                                     attribute: NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute
                                                    multiplier: 0.0
                                                      constant: 10.0];

    [self.inputView addConstraint: _heightConstraint];
```

But it is load me a new view (for example just one row) with height of previews view(3 rows) , very spread.

Answer (score 0):

From your question, it looks that you are having your custom keyboard just a simple UIView.

Now for changing the height of that view, you need to have one fixed height constraint in your autolayout of view, now you need make `IBOutlet` of height constraint on custom UIView object. Then whenever you want to change the height of that view, you just need to change the constant value of the IBoutlet of height constratint.

Comment: My keyboard is a UIView with many buttons with many constraints, I want to load another UIView. with different height, it is possible?

Comment: but how change the height? it is load the new view with previous height.

I adding my code

Comment: Change the constant value of height constraint as _heightConstraint.constant = _valueYouWant.

Comment: How can i get the in the code i added , i do it but it is still spread, i miss something there?

Comment: When you are loading new view on button click event, at that time change heightConstraint constant value